# VMware Horizon Client icon not deleting

Tags: slingshot, thirdpartyapps

I tried to uninstall VMware Horizon Client and so I opened the files as root and deleted the files for it in /lib directory and the icon was still there and so I deleted it in a menu editor that I installed earlier but it went into the /home/local/share/applications directory, messing up my wingpanel. Therefore I deleted it but it went back into my menu, and the cycle repeated.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a program called menulibre to hide icons. I learned you do not want to delete these .desktop files, just hide them as WingPanel will break if .desktop files are deleted.

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

once installed, open up the menu editor. In the search bar on the top right search for your program. Then change the toggle to hide from menus and save. This should do it for you.